# JSP - All scopes are empty inside the jsp:include page

Tags: java, jsp, scope, requestscope

I want to put a variable in the `requestScope` so I can use it in an other page. Unfortunately, the `requestScope` is totally empty in this other page. In fact, when I print `#{requestScope}` in both pages, they don't have the same memory adresse !

### mainPage.jsp

```
<c:set var="foo" value="${myForm.myJavaObject}" scope="request" />

<c:forEach var="scope" items="${requestScope}">
    ${scope.key} // PRINTS EVERY VARIABLE IN THE REQUEST SCOPE, INCLUDING foo
</c:forEach>

<jsp:include page="./includedPage.jsp"/>
```

### includedPage.jsp

```
<c:forEach var="scope" items="${requestScope}">
    ${scope.key} // PRINTS NOTHING
</c:forEach>
```

Same thing if try different scopes (session, application etc.). I don't get it. This method is all over the internet, so why is it not working? First time I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I include `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`. I don't get why though, as it is already included in the `mainPage.jsp` and because `<jsp:include>` is dynamic.